# What is the Difference between window.element and element while accessing DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I like understand how browser differentiates between hello and window.hello in below-given code

http://jsfiddle.net/PH3t2/291/

```js
var hello = "new hello";
console.log("variable hello : " + hello); // <-- prints "new hello"
console.log(window.hello); // <-- logs HTML elements
```

```html
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="mainBox" id="hello">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="clear" id="hello"></div>
</div>
```

How does specified window print HTML elements rather than the string `"new hello"`?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is because by default the browser stores all elements as properties of the `window` keyed by their `id` attribute - this is part of the reason you cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`, which is why the HTML you've shown is invalid.

It's also why `window.hello` returns an Element object - it's a reference to the first `<div>` in your HTML.

Similarly, the browser knows that when you define the `hello` variable you want a value stored separately from the reference it has to the `window.hello` element. This is why `hello` returns the `"new hello"` string.

Comment: The key part here is that jsfiddle wraps the code inside a window onload event so `var hello` becomes a local variable. If you remove the wrapper, `window.hello` refers to the variable: http://jsfiddle.net/PH3t2/292/